How can I generate a VAPID key pair for FCM without using the firebase console?
I would like to generate a VAPID key pair for my firebase project as part of my CI/CD pipeline. The only information I can find for performing this action is to use the firebase console UI, which is not a valid option for me. As far as I can tell, there is no documentation on how to do this using either the firebase SDK, or any REST endpoints.
I have tried using the same endpoint that the console uses (https://mobilesdk-pa.clients6.google.com/v1/projects/<project-id>/vapidKeys:createVapidKey), but have been unable to authenticate with this endpoint using a service account. I believe this is because when authenticating via a service account, the call is directed to the service account's project, which cannot have the private API (mobilesdk-pa) enabled. The curl command for my request is as follows:
local url="https://mobilesdk-pa.clients6.google.com/v1/projects/${PROJECT_NUMBER}/vapidKeys:createVapidKey"
local response=$(curl -s -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Content-Length: 0" \
    -H "x-goog-user-project: ${PROJECT_NUMBER}" \
    "${url}")
echo "Create VAPID key response: $response" >&2

Are there any alternative methods of authentication I could use on this endpoint that could work? Or, is there another endpoint available that I have missed?
